# Inserting multiple data Laravel 4

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to loop a form and insert the multiple inputs into the database all at the same time.The loop form runs fine but when I tried to click the submit button, it will only insert the inputs from the very last form. In what part have I done wrong?

filename.blade.php

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
      @for ($i = 0; $i < $gcount; $i++)
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>{{ Form::label('title','*Title ',array('class'=>'class="control-label"')) }}</td>
              <td>{{ Form::select('title', ['Mr'=>'Mr', 'Ms'=>'Ms'],'Mr',array('class'=>'form-control')) }} </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>{{ Form::label('birthday','*Birthday', array('class'=>'"input-group-addon btn"'))}}</td>
              <td>{{ Form::text('birthday', '', array('id' => 'calum','data-date-format'=>'yyyy-mm-dd','class' => 'form-control')) }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>{{ Form::label('name','*Name ',array('class'=>'class="control-label"')) }} </td>
              <td>{{ Form::text('lastname', '',array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'lastname'))}}</td>
              <td>{{ Form::text('firstname', '',array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'firstname'))}}</td>
              <td>{{ Form::text('middlename', '',array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'middlename'))}}</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
         <hr>
      @endfor
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td><p class="text-right">{{ Form::submit('Submit',array('class'=>'btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block')) }}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
  </div>
```

filenameController.php

```
$reserve = new Reserves;
foreach( $reserve as $key => $value) {
    $reserve->title = Input::get('title');
    $reserve->lastname = Input::get('lastname');
    $reserve->firstname= Input::get('firstname');
    $reserve->middlename = Input::get('middlename');
    $reserve->save(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is your form. You should change names of all form fields from `title` to `title[]` - so you should add `[]` to all your all form fields (title, lastname, firstname, middlename), probably also for birthday (but you don't use it here)

Now you should do something like this:

```
$c = count(Input::get('title'));

$titles = Input::get('title');
$lastnames = Input::get('lastname');
$firstnames = Input::get('firstname');
$middlenames = Input::get('middlename');

for ( $i=0; $i< $c; ++$i) {
    $reserve = new Reserves;
    $reserve->title = $titles[$i];
    $reserve->lastname = $lastnames[$i];
    $reserve->firstname= $firstnames[$i];
    $reserve->middlename = $middlenames[$i];
    $reserve->save(); 
}
```

Comment: I've tried the code you've suggested sir but it would give me 'Undefined variable: reserve'

Comment: Quite of a dumb question but why does it gives me a syntax error about foreach semicolon? 'syntax error, unexpected ';''

Comment: @staphhelpme IT should be `for` obviously, not `foreach`

Comment: It inserts now but the problem is it will only insert the last entry and the very 1st letter of every data.

Comment: Have you added `[]` to all form fields? Edit your question and show how your form looks like now

Comment: I missed out a few details sir. Sorry for that. Now it all works! One question sir, Why place []?

Comment: @staphhelpme Because you cannot have many fields with the same name. When using `[]` you create array so you can now use multiple fields with name ending with `[]`

Comment: Ah now I get it. Thank you so much sir! Gratitude

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$reserve = new Reserves;
foreach( $reserve as $key => $value) {
    $reserve->title = Input::get('title');
    $reserve->lastname = Input::get('lastname');
    $reserve->firstname= Input::get('firstname');
    $reserve->middlename = Input::get('middlename');
    $reserve->save(); 
}
```

to

```
foreach( $reserve as $key => $value) {
    $reserve = new Reserves;
    $reserve->title = Input::get('title');
    $reserve->lastname = Input::get('lastname');
    $reserve->firstname= Input::get('firstname');
    $reserve->middlename = Input::get('middlename');
    $reserve->save(); 
}
```

As this will create a different model each round in the loop. You were creating a single model then updating it many times.

Comment: tried this one but it gives me an error. 'Undefined variable: reserve'

Answer (score 0):

Use `Eloquent::insert()`

**Example**:

```
$data =[];

foreach( $x as $y) {
    $data[] = [
        'title'      => $y->title,
        'lastname'   => $y->lastname,
        'firstname'  => $y->firstname,
        'middlename' => $y->middlename
    ];
}
Model::insert($data);
```